# Stripe in wkwebview open a browser page loading script

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, wkwebview, cordova-ios

we're moving with our APP to new new wkweview due to the apple requirements.

One of APPs, is using StripeJS sdk in order to allow payment in app. Problem occurs when APP is bootstraping and the stripe sdk is include with the following code:

```
// Payment service is not initialized yet
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        url: "https://js.stripe.com/v3/",
        dataType: "script",
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          Logger.error("An error ocurred during SDK download");
          def.reject();
        },
        success: function() {
          Logger.debug("Stipe JDK downloaded correctly");
          initialized = true;
          def.resolve();
        }
      });
```

We already tried to use '' head tag in the index.html or creating dynamically one script TAG and appenging it to the body: but no one fix the problem.

**Script Inclusion Tests**

[Angular $http method]

```
$http({
   method: "GET",
   url: "https://js.stripe.com/v3/"
}).then(
   function(res) {
      angular.element("body").append("<script>" + res.data + "</script>");
   }, function(err) {
      def.reject();
   });
```

[index.html]

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  ...
```

**Problem**

A browser page is opened and APP is left in the background; being more specific, the "METRICS_CONTROLLER" case is catch in switch at row 767 ( see library at url < https://js.stripe.com/v3/ > ).

Have anyone an idea why including that script the browser page is opened ?

Comment: Are you attempting to load Stripe.js from a local cached copy using this method? That won't work, as Stripe.js must always be included from Stripe's servers directly.

Comment: The above method is just an example - head tag or angular $http load way is not cached - but the problem persists :(

Comment: If that's an example, can you provide the exact code you're using to include Stripe.js? It should always be included directly from Stripe's site, and not by loading it locally (which is what that example looks like it leads to).

Comment: Thanks taintedzodiac for answer. I edit post adding script inclusion add test. Simon

Comment: I also moved an Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4, and the issue appeared. I also tried to dynamically insert the script, and the page opens. Even after coming back to the application, if you try to make a payment, this will open new pages again. Stripe support said that they do not actively support cordova integration. My solution was to make a credit card form within the app, and manage all the stripe process (payment intent, payment method, subscription...) in my back end

Comment: @saperlipopette try to see if my answer help you. Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem.

The problem was about permission to navigate url not allowed by the cordova configuration ( file 'config.xml' ). More specifically, we need to add the following row in our config. file

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

So finally, our CORS permission definition is:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

'*' is due to the fact that the APP can trigger outside resource, so we cannot known which url will be opened by user in APP.